# Create a Dropdown Menu that when clicked displays a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to code a dropdown menu that when a option is clicked, it displays a *div* with that options name, but I can't figure out how to do just that.

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        <select id="type">
            <option value="Gradients">Gradients</option>
            <option value="Custom Color">Custom Color</option>
            <option value="Custom Image/Video">Custom Image/Video</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="Gradients" class="data">
        <h1>gradient</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Custom Color" class="data">
        <h1>color</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Custom Image/Video" class="data">
        <h1>image/video</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to set the style.display property to block

Comment: your answer is good but it has lack of representation, try to add example also.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```js
const dropMenu = document.querySelector('#type'),
sections = document.querySelectorAll('.data');

dropMenu.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('#' + event.target.value).classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}

.data.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu">
            <select id="type">
                 <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Gradients">Gradients</option>
                <option value="Custom-Color">Custom Color</option>
                <option value="Custom-Image">Custom Image/Video</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="Gradients" class="data">
            <h1>gradient</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="Custom-Color" class="data">
            <h1>color</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="Custom-Image" class="data">
            <h1>image/video</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```